# NIFI not starting | org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiCoreException: Unable to start Flow Controller

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to re-start NiFi and getting following exception.

```
2016-04-22 09:27:30,672 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Failed to start web server... shutting down.
org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiCoreException: Unable to start Flow Controller.
        at org.apache.nifi.web.contextlistener.ApplicationStartupContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupContextListener.java:99) ~[na:na]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:800) ~[jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:791) ~[jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349) ~[jetty-webapp-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342) ~[jetty-webapp-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741) ~[jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505) ~[jetty-webapp-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132) ~[jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114) ~[jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61) ~[jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132) ~[jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387) ~[jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114) ~[jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61) ~[jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354) ~[jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:663) ~[nifi-jetty-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:137) [nifi-runtime-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:227) [nifi-runtime-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowService': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowController': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Write-Ahead Log located at ./state/local/snapshot was written using the  class; cannot restore using org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:175) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1585) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1060) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.nifi.web.contextlistener.ApplicationStartupContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupContextListener.java:64) ~[na:na]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowController': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Write-Ahead Log located at ./state/local/snapshot was written using the  class; cannot restore using org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:175) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1585) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1060) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.nifi.spring.StandardFlowServiceFactoryBean.getObject(StandardFlowServiceFactoryBean.java:53) ~[nifi-framework-core-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Write-Ahead Log located at ./state/local/snapshot was written using the  class; cannot restore using org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController.<init>(FlowController.java:435) ~[nifi-framework-core-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController.createStandaloneInstance(FlowController.java:364) ~[nifi-framework-core-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
        at org.apache.nifi.spring.FlowControllerFactoryBean.getObject(FlowControllerFactoryBean.java:66) ~[nifi-framework-core-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Write-Ahead Log located at ./state/local/snapshot was written using the  class; cannot restore using org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog
        at org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.recoverFromSnapshot(MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.java:355) ~[nifi-write-ahead-log-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
        at org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.recoverRecords(MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.java:292) ~[nifi-write-ahead-log-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.state.providers.local.WriteAheadLocalStateProvider.init(WriteAheadLocalStateProvider.java:99) ~[nifi-framework-core-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.state.providers.AbstractStateProvider.initialize(AbstractStateProvider.java:34) ~[nifi-framework-core-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.state.manager.StandardStateManagerProvider.createStateProvider(StandardStateManagerProvider.java:186) ~[nifi-framework-core-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.state.manager.StandardStateManagerProvider.createLocalStateProvider(StandardStateManagerProvider.java:80) ~[nifi-framework-core-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.state.manager.StandardStateManagerProvider.create(StandardStateManagerProvider.java:66) ~[nifi-framework-core-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController.<init>(FlowController.java:433) ~[nifi-framework-core-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
        ... 38 common frames omitted
2016-04-22 09:27:30,674 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Initiating shutdown of Jetty web server...
```

Error says that it is caused by Write-Ahead Log located at ./state/local/snapshot was written using the  class; cannot restore using org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog

Bu i am not sure what does that mean?

Can someone help me here?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi, which NiFi version is that? Did you perform an upgrade previously?

Comment: I am using 0.5 version. I havent performed any upgrade.

Comment: Is it a clean install? Do you see this after a crash maybe? Trying to understand if there was any data in the pipeline before. And I would strongly recommend upgrading to the 0.6.1, current GA.

Comment: Yes. It is a clean install. I had downloaded tar file and extracted it.

Comment: I wonder if this could be related to a Java runtime. What do you see when you run `java --version'? Make sure it's not some GCJ, but rather an Oracle JDK or OpenJDK, both 7 and 8 will work.

Also, if you had no data in this instance, upgrade to 0.6.1 to pick up some fixes in this area, save some troubleshooting time.

Answer (score 0):

This question is likely to be specific to the (now very old) 0.5 version of Nifi.

Based on the comment of @andrew the wrong JDK is the prime suspect.

> What do you see when you run `java --version'? Make sure it's not some GCJ, but rather an Oracle JDK or OpenJDK, both 7 and 8 will work.